# How do I add a sub list with different bullets in Pages

Tags: pages

What I want is a list with the following levels of indentation:

```
1. Test  
    a. Test  
        i. Test  
    b. Test
        i. Test  
        ii. Test  
        iii. Test
2. Test
```

I can't get seem to use two different styles for indentation; I get a list like this:

```
1. Test
    1. Test
        1. Test
    2. Test
        1. Test
        2. Test
        3. Test
2. Test
```

How would I achieve what I want in Pages automatically?

Comment: I see you’re a new contributor here, so: congrats on your first question, and welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

You can use different Bullets & Lists style for different indentation level in Pages.

After entering the 1st level item (i.e. 1. Test in your case), simply press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This will automatically create a list, mark the entered text as the 1st item of list, assign default spacing between text and the number, and add numbering for the second item on the next line.

Now, simply press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to create a sub-list. Change the bullet & list style as desired under Format sidebar.

Repeat for every subsequent level of indentation.

Comment: I was looking more for a solution that changes the bullet style automatically when I press Tab

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is nearly 4 years too late but if you go into the bullet list you can click the + sign to add a new one and name it whatever you want. Then design the bullet list with the different styles for each level of indentation and when you are done go back to the bullet list and click the "Update" button next to the custom list name you created. After that it will automatically use the bullet styles you chose for each level rather than having to change it every time.[image: Screenshot with steps]